# Why are NSAttributedString's attributes now of type [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] but UITextView's typingAttributes are still of type [String: Any]?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, swift4

I used to be able to generate `NSAttributedString`s and set a `UITextView`'s `typingAttributes` using the same attribute dictionary (most especially the same keys) of type `[String: Any]`. Since iOS 11, I've had to change `[String: Any]` attributes to `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]`attributes for generating `NSAttributedString`s, yet `UITextView`s still remain of type `[String: Any]`. Why?

Comment: FYI - this has nothing to do with Swift 4. The use of `NSAttributedStringKey` is change in the API as of iOS 11, etc. It's the same whether you use Swift 4, Swift 3, or Objective-C.

Comment: Weird, the compile-time warnings only popped up after I converted from Swift 3.2 to Swift 4 in Xcode 9

Comment: Doesn't seem to be unified for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` as well but nonetheless you can just convert it like so

```
func ConvertToTypingAttributes(_ attr: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    var result = [String: Any]()
    for (k,v) in attr {
        result[k.rawValue] = v
    }
    return result
}
```

USAGE:

```
var txtView = UITextView()
let p: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: UIColor.green]
txtView.typingAttributes = ConvertToTypingAttributes(p)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question wasn't asking for a way to convert it, rather an explanation.

Comment: Since the question isn't asking for a conversion, I won't add this as an answer. Here is another option: `extension Dictionary where Key == NSAttributedStringKey {
 func asTypingAttributes() -> [String: Any] {
  var result = [String: Any]()
  for (key, value) in self {
   result[key.rawValue] = value
  }
  return result
 }
}`